# twisted CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am using scrapy-splash to crawl this website and the spider is giving  "[twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:"

Tried everything on the stack overflow and other websites

Code of my spider

```
class DarazspidySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'darazspidy'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.daraz.pk/smartphones/'
        SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, 
     endpoint='render.html', args={'wait': 0.5})

    def parse(self, response):
        for phone in response.xpath('//div[@class="c5TXIP"]'):
            yield {
            'Name',
            phone.xpath('.//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "c16H9d", " " ))]//a').extract(),
            'price',
            phone.xpath('.//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "c13VH6", " " ))]').extract(),
        }
```

Comment: Can you try to `yield` your `SplashRequest`?

Comment: what do mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are yielding a set, not a dictionary. Can you try to yield a dictionary instead?

Your set creation will fail because you can't add lists into a set.

Try something like this instead:

```
def parse(self, response):
        for phone in response.xpath('//div'):
            yield {
            'Name': phone.xpath('.//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "c16H9d", " " ))]//a').extract(),
            'price': phone.xpath('.//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "c13VH6", " " ))]').extract(),
        }
```

You probably also need to yeild your splash request:

```
yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, 
     endpoint='render.html', args={'wait': 0.5})
```